# Where should i declare a new firebase database instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

When using [`const db = firebase.database()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database), does it matter where I declare this in a cloud function script?

For example, `index.ts` which contains all of my cloud functions, should I declare it at the top, or in each individual function?

```
const db = firebase.database()
export const functionA = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
   // use db here
});
export const functionB = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
   // use db here
});
```

**OR**

```
export const functionA = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const db = firebase.database()
});
export const functionB = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const db = firebase.database()
});
```

Or does this not matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach creates the `db` instance when the code **loads**.

The second approach creates the `db` instance when the code **runs**.

Neither is pertinently better than the other, and the `firebase.database()` operation is very lightweight so it's likely to make little difference in practice.

What *does* make a difference is whether you load the database SDK to begin with. Some of the SDKs in Firebase are quite big, and not each Cloud Function needs all SDKs. So a common trick to speed up load/cold-start times is to move the `require('firebase-...')` statements *into* the body of the Cloud Function(s) that require them.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if you want to interact, from a Cloud Function, with the Realtime Database you just need to initialize the Admin SDK and get the Database service for the default app (or a given app), as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database) in the doc.

So you would do something like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
// Get the Database service for the default app
const db = admin.database();
```

---

To get more details on what Frank explains about Cold Start in his answer, you should read the following article: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/organize-cloud-functions-for-max-cold-start-performance-and-readability-with-typescript-and-9261ee8450f0

However in your case, since your two Cloud Functions use the Admin SDK, there shouldn't be any difference between the two approaches presented in your question, as Frank mentioned.